# NBRL-Gamepad bluetooth controller recognized only as serial device

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, gamepad

I have a bluetooth gamepad that it was compatible with nibiru platform for Android. I have tried the solutions for IPEGA bluetooth gamepad but, i could make it work.

It connects but it is not recognised as gamepad as you can see in the following picture :
[Bluetooth connection mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWYnj.jpg)

It creates a serial connection with it but it doesn't create an event on /dev/input or at least, i couldn't find it.

It might be something simple. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!